# how can i make a text file on azure blob storage by using PowerShell Runbook?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure and trying to make a text file on azure blob strage by PowerShell Runbook like this:
`echo "test" > test.txt`

But I cannot. I think `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` is good to do this but I have no idea what arguments should be specified.

What arguments should be added to the following command line?

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "test123" -UseConnectedAccount
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "test_files" -Context $ctx (what should I add here?)
```

Comment: Where are you running that PowerShell? Where would you expect the file to be created? Please provide us with enough (relevant) information and refer to [ask]. On-topic: Check out the [Set-AzStorageBlobContent documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-AzStorageblobcontent)

Comment: are you trying to create txt file from blob storage ? what exactly are you looking for ? Can you please provide the more details

Comment: i am running the powershell on PowerShell Runbook.

Comment: my boss required me to make a file on blob strage without making a physical file. i need to make bolb file from variable directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to create a temp file since the `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` command wants a file.

`Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "ContosoUpload" -File ".\PlanningData" -Blob "Planning2015"`

If you need to create temporary files as part of your runbook logic, you can use the Temp folder (that is, `$env:TEMP`) in the Azure sandbox for runbooks running in Azure. The only limitation is you cannot use more than 1 GB of disk space, which is the quota for each sandbox. When working with PowerShell workflows, this scenario can cause a problem because PowerShell workflows use checkpoints and the script could be retried in a different sandbox.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#temporary-storage-in-a-sandbox